# DB::listen not working in controller, Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

The below query prints the count of users table and the echo statement what i have given. Wondering why its not printing the sql query as per the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database) says.

```
$count = DB::table('users')->count();
        echo $count;
        DB::listen(function($query){
             echo $query->sql;
         });
        echo 'End of the script';
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database#listening-for-query-events), you need to register the `Database` listener inside of your `Service provider`

> If you would like to receive each SQL query executed by your application, you may use the  listen method. This method is useful for logging queries or debugging. **You may register your query listener in a service provider**

So put `DB::listen` inside a `boot`method of your `AppServiceProvider` and do `echo` there

**EDIT:**

Using `\DB::listen` is incorrect because the namespace of `DB` facade is not inside of `App\Http\ServiceProviders\` or whatever the namespace of `AppServiceProvider` is, but it is rather `Illuminate\Support\Facades\`.

**Please change `\DB::listen` to `Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::listen` or put a `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;` at the top of your `Service Provider` and then do `DB::listen` or if you have it registered in your `aliases` inside of `config/app.php` then you can do `use DB;`**

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  So each and every time I have to comment (once we have done the debug) and uncomment this in AppServiceProvider, am i right.                         \DB::listen(function($query){
            echo $query->sql;
            var_dump($query->bindings);
            echo $query->time;
        });

Comment: What you do with the listener is totally up to you. When you put `DB::listen` inside of the service provider it will listen for **ALL** queries